# Swift import error when compiling main: no such module 'NIO' or 'NIOHTTP2'

Tags: swift, ubuntu

I have installed Swift on Ubuntu ARM inside Docker and my package.Swift file looks like this:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.9.0
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Swift-Test",
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-nio.git", from: "2.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-http2.git", from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .executableTarget(
            name: "Swift-Test", 
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "NIO", package: "swift-nio"),
                .product(name: "NIOHTTP2", package: "swift-nio-http2"),
            ],
            path: "."
        ),
    ]
)
```

And I am trying to learn and play around with building a HTTP server, so my main file looks like:

```
import Foundation
import NIO
import NIOHTTP2

let group = MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup(numberOfThreads: System.coreCount)

do {
    let bootstrap = try ServerBootstrap(group: group)
        .serverChannelOption(ChannelOptions.socket(SocketOptionLevel(SOL_SOCKET), SO_REUSEADDR), value: 1)
        .childChannelInitializer { channel in
            let http2Handlers: [ChannelHandler] = [
                NIOHTTP2Handler(mode: .server),
                HelloWorldHandler() // Your custom handler for responding with "Hello, World!"
            ]
            return channel.pipeline.addHandlers(http2Handlers)
        }
        .childChannelOption(ChannelOptions.socket(IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY), value: 1)
        .childChannelOption(ChannelOptions.socket(SocketOptionLevel(SOL_SOCKET), SO_REUSEADDR), value: 1)

    let host = "127.0.0.1"
    let port = 8080

    let serverChannel = try bootstrap.bind(host: host, port: port).wait()
    print("Server started and listening on \(serverChannel.localAddress!)")
    try serverChannel.closeFuture.wait()
} catch {
    print("Server error: \(error)")
}

// Custom handler to respond with "Hello, World!"
final class HelloWorldHandler: ChannelInboundHandler {
    typealias InboundIn = HTTP2Frame.FramePayload
    typealias OutboundOut = HTTP2Frame.FramePayload

    func channelRead(context: ChannelHandlerContext, data: NIOAny) {
        // Handle HTTP/2 requests and respond with "Hello, World!" as needed.
        // You can inspect the HTTP/2 frames here.
    }
}
```

However when I run the following commands:

```
swift package clean
swift package resolve
swift build
```

I get a few warnings but, then if I run `swift main.swift` I get this error: `main.swift:2:8: error: no such module 'NIO' import NIO`

I can see everything for NIO and NIOHTTP2 building but, my main file cannot import it correctly and I don't know why.

I am also using a flat directory, there are no folders, just my package file and a `mian.swift` and the `.build`.

I am new to Swift. Any ideas why I cannot use my NIO import?